# Entity framework override dbset in child context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

Phone19 class inherits Phone class and contains additional fields. The idea here is to extend the existing database model using TPH (Table per hierarchy) approach. I enable migrations for both contexts via PM console, they are using correct contexts, but when I add a migration to "parent" migration adds the fields from Phone19 class. Is there a way I can override IDbset? I cannot make it virtual and override it later since one is using Phone class and the other one is using class Phone19

There is a base context that looks like this

```
public class CallTrackingDBContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }


    private void InitContext()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 100000;
    }

    public CallTrackingDBContext(DbConnection dbConnection) : base(dbConnection,false)
    {
        InitContext();
    }

    public CallTrackingDBContext() : base("CallTrackingDBContext")
    {
        InitContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

And there is another context that inherits the previous one and should override Phones Dbset:

```
public class ClientContext19 : CallTrackingDBContext
{
    public new IDbSet<Phone19> Phones { get; set; }

    public ClientContext19(DbConnection dbConnection) : base(dbConnection)
    {
        InitContext();
    }

    public ClientContext19() : base("DBContext19")
    {

        InitContext();
    }


    private void InitContext()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 100000;
    }
}
```

Comment: "...migration adds the fields from Phone19 class..." isn't that what you want?

Comment: it adds the fields to the parent database as well, while it should only add them to the database that is targeted by ClientContext19

Comment: The problem is that the Code First conventions (and migrations) are going to treat the addition of Phone19 as an extension of the original model, and adjust as such.  Do you need to treat it as a subclass of `Phone` in the new context, or should every "phone" in that model be a `Phone19`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave `Phone19` out of the convention-based model using a `NotMappedAttribute`.  In the new model weave it back in using the fluent configuration.

```
public class ClientContext19 : CallTrackingDbContext
{
  ...

  public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dmb)
  {
    dmb.Entity<Phone>()
      .Map<Phone19>(m => m.Requires("discriminator").HasValue("Phone19"));
  }
}
```

You can customize the discriminator column name and value, or even just require that one of the properties on `Phone19` has a value to mark a row as being a `Phone19` and not a `Phone`.